# My CSS won't display: inline; for my buttons

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.kbb.com/scion/fr-s/2013/" class="button">YES</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="2"> 
    <ul>
    <li><a href="http://tinyurl.com/nk4k25r" class="button">NO</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="3">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="http://tinyurl.com/pnaj3j2"  class="button">YES</a></li>

</div>
<div class="4">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="http://tinyurl.com/qybshxz" class="button">NO</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.button {
        display: block;
        height: 100px;
        width: 200px;
        background: #ffff00;
        border: 2px solid #00E5EE;
        color: #551A8B;

        text-align: center;
        font: bold 3.2em/100px Impact;

        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffff00, #2f5f63);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffff00, #2f5f63);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffff00, #2f5f63);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffff00, #2f5f63);
        background: linear-gradient(top, #ffff00, #2f5f63);

        -khtml-border-radius: 50px;
        -moz-border-radius: 50px;
        border-radius: 90px;
        margin: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    div li {
        display: inline;
        float: center;
    }
```

I'm working on getting my buttons to align in the center of the page and inline but every time I try to use `display: inline;` my buttons get smaller and stay vertical.

Comment: You must close `.button` class and maybe what you are looking after is `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.button` has `display:block;` so you can centering by `margin:0 auto;` and `float` property doesn't have `center` value.

```css
.button {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #ffff00;
  border: 2px solid #00E5EE;
  color: #551A8B;
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 3.2em/100px Impact;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffff00, #2f5f63);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffff00, #2f5f63);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffff00, #2f5f63);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffff00, #2f5f63);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #ffff00, #2f5f63);
  -khtml-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 90px;
  margin: 0px auto 15px;
}
div li {
  display: block;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.kbb.com/scion/fr-s/2013/" class="button">YES</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://tinyurl.com/nk4k25r" class="button">NO</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="3">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://tinyurl.com/pnaj3j2" class="button">YES</a>
    </li>

</div>
<div class="4">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://tinyurl.com/qybshxz" class="button">NO</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. It is centered which is what I wanted but, I want my buttons to line up horizontally. No display attribute seems to help me with that. Thank you for all the help

Comment: @JinAG What do you mean by line up horizontally?

Comment: @JinAG It's the `div` elements that are sitting next to each other. They are the elements that need setting to `inline-block`

Comment: @alirezasafian The buttons are in rows

Comment: @alirezasafian It has worked! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your css as

```
.button {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #ffff00;
  border: 2px solid #00E5EE;
  color: #551A8B;
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 3.2em/100px Impact;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffff00, #2f5f63);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffff00, #2f5f63);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffff00, #2f5f63);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffff00, #2f5f63);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #ffff00, #2f5f63);
  -khtml-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 90px;
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

and HTMl as

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.kbb.com/scion/fr-s/2013/" class="button">YES</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="2">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://tinyurl.com/nk4k25r" class="button">NO</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <div class="3">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://tinyurl.com/pnaj3j2" class="button">YES</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <div class="4">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://tinyurl.com/qybshxz" class="button">NO</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```